# using v-for to iterate through json where id's are all different and bind them to Input in PrimeVue

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, vuejs2, primevue

I have a database of products with a column called `attributes` that stores property/value pairs as JSON.  For example, I could have a product, that product will have attributes, but the attributes are never the same for each product.  So one product might look like:

```
#product1
attributes {
  color: "green",
  size: "small"
}
```

While another might look like:

```
#product2
attributes {
  width: "12inches",
  height: "11inches
}
```

I'm setting up a form to CRUD products, including these dynamic attributes.  So far it look like this:

[image]

I'm using PrimeVue to create this app and form, and am trying to bind these property/value pairs to some [PrimeVue components (InputText)](https://www.primefaces.org/primevue/showcase/#/inputtext).  They require a vue data property to be binded using `v-model` on the input.  The screenshot above is coded here:

```
<InputText v-model="product.attribute_property" id="attribute_property" placeholder="key" />
  <span class="p-inputgroup-addon"> : </span>
<InputText v-model="product.attribute_value" id="attribute_value" placeholder="value" />
```

Binded to these:

```
export default {
    data() {
        return {
          product {
            
          }
      }
    }
}
```

After parsing the incoming JSON from the database table, it looks like this (this is Vue dev tools):
[image]

My plan was to use `v-for` to iterate through the properties and their values and dynamically create each Input, but that doesn't work.  I know it's due to my poverty of knowledge with how all of this works.  I tried:

```
<div v-for="(value, key) in attributes" :key="key">
  <div class="p-inputgroup">
    <InputText v-model="key" id="attributes_key" placeholder="key" />
    <span class="p-inputgroup-addon">&nbsp;:&nbsp;</span>
    <InputText v-model="value" id="attributes_value" placeholder="value" />
  </div>
</div>
```

But it complains that  `'v-model' directives cannot update the iteration variable 'key' itself`.  I know I'm not iterating through the JSON correctly, but I don't know the right or best way to do it.  The end goal here is to bind these properties to the inputs and create dynamic attributes for the products.  I'm just not sure how to loop with `v-for` to access the property/value pairs.  Many thanks.

Comment: As the error states, you cannot edit the key directly. You'd need to extract the key value pairs into a new array of objects and reference this new array while editing and reconstruct the products once you are done editing.

Comment: I think that is what is confusing me... I'm already putting the values into a new data property and parsing the JSON during `mounted()`
    `this.attributes = JSON.parse(this.prod.attributes);`

Comment: So here is where I'm at.  https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-williams-68b4l?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue
I'm able to get the value of the attributes, but not the key.  I'm not sure how to reference the name of the attribute in my v-model.

Comment: Give me a few minutes. I will give it a go.

Comment: have a look at here, hope this puts you in the right direction: https://codesandbox.io/s/red-mountain-1zlni?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue

Comment: I do believe that will do it!  I didn't think to rebuild the object with static keys, naming each value. Thank you!  If you'd like to answer I'll be glad to accept.

Comment: That needed to be done since object keys couldnt be directly manipulated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extending on the comments:

> As the error states, you cannot edit the key directly. You'd need to extract the key value pairs into a new array of objects and reference this new array while editing and reconstruct the products once you are done editing.

Extract the key value pair into a new array of objects,

```
..
data() {
return {
  attributes: {
    color: "green",
    size: "small",
  },
  newAttributes: [],
 };
},

//once mounted:
mounted: function () {
 let attributes = this.attributes;
 let keys = Object.keys(attributes);
 let newValues = [];
 keys.forEach((attrKey, i) => {
   let s = {};
   s["key"] = attributes[attrKey];
   s["val"] = attrKey;
   newValues.push(s);
 });
 this.newAttributes = newValues;
},
```

Loop through the `newAttributes` array and when updated reconstruct the products array, for example, in a computed variable

```
computed: {
 reFormattedAttributes: function () {
   let attributes = this.newAttributes;
   let formatted = {};
   Array.from(attributes).forEach((attribute) => {
     formatted[attribute["key"]] = attribute["val"];
   });
   return formatted;
 },
},
```